# Using python libary simplejson and urllib in PostGIS

Tags: python, postgresql

I installed PostGreSQL9.3 and want to create a Pl/Python function using simplejson library and urllib. First I use OSGeo4W Shell to test the similar python script, it works. Then in PostgreSQL, it doesn't work; the error info is "can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION scratch.GetWeather(lon float, lat float)
RETURNS float
AS $$
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import json as simplejson
    data = urlopen('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/station?lat=%s&lon=%s&cnt=1' % (lat, lon))
    js_data = simplejson.load(data)
    if js_data['cod'] == '200':        
        if int(js_data['cnt'])>0:
            station = js_data['list'][0]
            print ('Data from weather station %s' % station['name'])
            if 'main' in station:
                if 'temp' in station['main']:
                    temperature = station['main']['temp'] - 273.15
                else:
                    temperature = None
            else:
                temperature = None
        else:
            temperature = None
        return temperature

    $$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

Error message is

```
"TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "getweather", line 5, in <module>
    js_data = simplejson.load(data)..."
```

How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you just have to remove the single quotes from 200? '200' -> 200

Comment: If I remove single quotes, get the same result. Today I found I cannot install geopy for python3.2 (which is used by PostgreSQL9.3). Looks same reason: cannot install these library such as simplejason.